# how to get first child node value of a parent element

Tags: xslt

I have an xml like below, what I am trying to do is to fetch the text node of parent element using a match template.

```
<xml>
  <para>
    <text>
        para 1
    </text>
    <para>
      <text>
        para 2
      </text>     
    </para>
  </para>
</xml>
```

my xslt looks like below

```
<xsl:template match="para">
          <xsl:value-of select="../para/text/text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

for first para node it is not returning any text which is good but for 2nd one it is returning  para 1 para 2 where as it should return only para 1. Any help or hint how to achieve this?

Comment: I fixed your indentation to show the nesting correctly.  Is this still what you intended?  If that's the entire XSL the second `<para>` won't be seen at all as it is "consumed" when the template matched the outer `<para>`, unless you had an `apply-templates` somewhere else.  In fact, the output you are seeing is from matching the ***first*** `<para>`.  Please post enough of the XSLT that we can see what is _really_ happening. Without that, the question is not answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XML, the parent of the second `para` element is the first `para` element. That means that, if the second `para` is your context node then `../para/text/text()` will go up to the parent (the first `para`) down to all `para` children (there is only one - the second `para` again) and then select the text within the `text` child of that, which is `para 2`.

If you want the first text node of the parent `para` element then you should write

```
select="parent::para/text[1]"
```

However you need to write an `apply-templates` within the template so that the inner elements will be processed.